# Order by aggregate is really slow

Tags: postgresql, performance, graphql, hasura

I have a performance issue on my request (about 20s with a limit of 25 items)

Here is my tables :

```
event { 
    id uuid primary key
    title text not null
}
```

(5000 rows)

```
race {
    Id uuid primary key
    event__id uuid references event(id) not null
    start_date timestamptz
}
```

(10000 rows)

And my query :

```
query searchEvents($where: event_bool_exp!, $limit: Int!, $offset: Int!) {
  events: event(where: $where, limit: $limit, offset: $offset, order_by: {races_aggregate: {min: {start_date: asc}}}) {
    title
  }
  total: event_aggregate(where: $where) {
    aggregate {
      count
    }
  }
}
```

I can see the start_date : order_by which is very slow and I wonder how I can optimize that?
Any ideas?

I also ask on a open github issue : https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/5554

Comment: What indexes do you have?

Comment: i tried several indexes on race.start_date but none seems to optimize the query
Do you have any recommendations on that?

Comment: I wouldn't expect an index on start_date to be much good for this.  Based on the plan you posted on github, I would expect you to get a huge benefit from an index race.event__id

Comment: Wow thank you so much !!! i use hash index on race.event__id and now my request respond in 70ms